# Can someone explain to me why the following expression acts in the way it does

Tags: math, expression

When I run this code it returns 3 (as I expected) however j prints 0. Could someone explain why this happens.

```
 int i, j;
 i = 3;
 j = i;
 j = j/9*6;
 System.out.println(i);
 System.out.println(j);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are performing integer division, so j/9 will evaluate to 0, then 0*6 == 0.

Comment: Thank you I completely forgot that it's an integer which is kind of stupid.